# Smooth audio waveform

Tags: python, audio, smoothing

I get audio file's gain with librosa :

```
clip, sample_rate = librosa.load(self.file_path)
```

And then, I get the outline of the graph.

Now I need a way to smooth the 'staircases'.
[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qd0l.png)

So far scipy.signal savgol_filter was the best, but on my second file, it isn't smooth :
[savgol_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEqZt.png)

Here is the raw data :

```
file1_blue_topOne=[77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39]
file1_blue_botOne=[8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39]
file1_green_topOne=[64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39]
file1_green_botOne=[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39]
file1_grey_topOne=[81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39]



file2_blue_topOne=[77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,77,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36]
file2_blue_botOne=[28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36]
file2_green_topOne=[76,76,76,76,76,76,76,76,76,76,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,68,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,67,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,66,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,63,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,61,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,59,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,58,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,56,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,55,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,52,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,44,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,41,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,38,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36]
file2_green_botOne=[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,33,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36]
```